# Get object value from Observable (RxJava, Retrofit)

Tags: android, api, retrofit2, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I'm trying to learn to use Rxjava to make Api calls with retrofit. I have to make multiple api calls in a loop. I'm struggling with getting the value in my subscriber.

```
@GET("pokemon" + "/{id}")
fun getPokemonData(@Path("id") id: Int):
        Observable<Pokemon>
```

I'm expecting to get a Pokemon object in my Subscriber but instead I get a Observable. How do I transform it to a Pokemon object?

```
  Observable.fromIterable(list)
        .flatMap { it ->
            Observable
                .just(it.url)
                .map { PokeApi.retrofitService.getPokemonData(getPokemonIdFromUrl(it))
                }
        }
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe({
                //onNext --I'm expecting to get a Pokemon Object here, instead I get a Observable<Pokemon>

        }, {//onError} , {// do something when all api calls are done?})
```

My goal is to make api calls with ids in the "list" and get "notified" when all the api calls are finished. Is this the correct approach to solve this problem ?

Comment: what's `list`? At first sight, you shouldn't be experiencing what you describe.

Comment: list is a List<PokemonApiCallUrls> object type. where PokemonApiCallUrls is `data class PokemonApiCallUrls(val url: String)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems lies here:

```kotlin
Observable
   .just(it.url)
   .map { PokeApi.retrofitService.getPokemonData(getPokemonIdFromUrl(it)) }
```

When you use `map` it maps to the return object from `getPokemonData`. You probably want to `flatMap` it:

```kotlin
Observable
   .just(it.url)
   .flatMap { PokeApi.retrofitService.getPokemonData(getPokemonIdFromUrl(it)) }
```

which not only maps the result but flattens it too so you don't get an observable, but the result of that observable.